# Select Oracle result two lines for same cases

Tags: sql, oracle, select, view, oracle11g

I have this table in Oracle database 11g:

```
    NUNOTA  SEQUENCIA QTD_CONTROLE     QTDNEG
---------- ---------- ------------ ----------
       446          1           30         60
       446          2           30         30
       446          3           30        120
```

I need to obtain a result like that:

```
    NUNOTA  SEQUENCIA QTD_CONTROLE     QTDNEG
---------- ---------- ------------ ----------
       446          1           30         30
       446          1           30         30
       446          2           30         30
       446          3           30         30
       446          3           30         30
       446          3           30         30
       446          3           30         30
```

It is basicly QTDNEG / QTD_CONTROLE and the result must be the number of lines.

I will use the result to print labels, in FreeReport,

I tried to use Oracle Views to get the result but is to hard for me.

Another example:

```
    NUNOTA  SEQUENCIA QTD_CONTROLE     QTDNEG
---------- ---------- ------------ ----------
       446          1           30         60
       446          2          100        300
       446          3           15         30
```

The result should be

```
    NUNOTA  SEQUENCIA QTD_CONTROLE     QTDNEG
---------- ---------- ------------ ----------
       446          1           30         30
       446          1           30         30
       446          2          100        100
       446          2          100        100
       446          2          100        100
       446          3           15         15
       446          3           15         15
```

Comment: You want the number of rows per nunota/sequencia that result from integer division?  Please be more specific.

Comment: I want a row per QTDNEG / QTD_CONTROLE

Comment: I think you want to split the rows per the multiples of 30 based on `QTDNEG` column, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, but do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with t_res (NUNOTA,SEQUENCIA,QTD_CONTROLE,QTDNEG, lvl) as (
  select NUNOTA,SEQUENCIA,QTD_CONTROLE,QTDNEG, 1
    from t
  union all
  select t.NUNOTA,t.SEQUENCIA,t.QTD_CONTROLE,t.QTDNEG, t_res.lvl + 1
    from t, t_res
   where t_res.lvl < t.QTDNEG/t.QTD_CONTROLE
)
select unique NUNOTA,SEQUENCIA,QTD_CONTROLE,QTD_CONTROLE, lvl
  from t_res
 order by SEQUENCIA, lvl


NUNOTA  SEQUENCIA   QTD_CONTROLE    QTD_CONTROLE    LVL
-------------------------------------------------------
   446          1             30              30      1
   446          1             30              30      2
   446          2             30              30      1
   446          3             30              30      1
   446          3             30              30      2
   446          3             30              30      3
   446          3             30              30      4
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution (available from Oracle 11gR2):

```
with t(nunota, sequencia, qtd_controle, qtdneg) as
  (select nunota
        , sequencia
        , qtd_controle
        , qtdneg
   from mytable
   union all
   select nunota
        , sequencia
        , qtd_controle
        , qtdneg - qtd_controle
   from t
   where qtdneg - qtd_controle > 0)
select nunota
     , sequencia
     , qtd_controle
     , least(qtdneg, qtd_controle)
from t
order by nunota
       , sequencia
       , least(qtdneg, qtd_controle) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is by generating a list of numbers that is "big enough" and then joining to that list.  I think the resulting query (in your case) is something like this:

```
with n(n) as (
      select level
      from dual
      where level <= 100
     )
select tt.NUNOTA, tt.SEQUENCIA, tt.QTD_CONTROLE, 30 as QTDNEG
from thistable tt join
     n
     on n.n <= tt.QTDNEG / tt.QTD_CONTROLE ;
```